# Implementing Custom dropdown in Angular 2/4

Tags: html, angular, dropdown, angular2-directives

I have been working on a custom dropdown functionality with a horizontal divider seperating two sets of values and have general select dropdown functionalities like using **up** and **down** arrow to navigate through the values, as well as go to specific values on *press* of a **alphabet**.

**Code:**

```
<div class="btn-group d-flex dropdown" dropdown>
<div class="floatLabelContainer w-100">
<button id="button-basic" dropdownToggle type="button" float-label [addLabel]="false" [hasFloat]="true" class="mb-2" aria-controls="dropdown-basic">
{{selectedCountry}}
<span class="caret" id="country-caret"></span>
</button>
<label for="button-basic" class="label-class" id="label-class">Country</label>
</div>
<ul id="dropdown-basic" slimScroll width="100%" height="250px" size="3px" alwaysVisible="true" wheelStep="20" *dropdownMenu
class="dropdown-menu d-block" role="menu" aria-labelledby="button-basic">
<li role="menuitem">
<a class="dropdown-item" tabindex="0" (click)="selectedCountry = country.name" *ngFor="let country of restOfCountries | orderBy : 'name'">{{country.name}}</a>
</li>
<li class="divider dropdown-divider"></li>
<li role="menuitem">
<a class="dropdown-item" tabindex="0" (click)="selectedCountry = country.name" *ngFor="let country of asianCountries | orderBy : 'name'">{{country.name}}</a>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

I have been able to achieve the divider part with the above code,

[image]

but is there away to implement arrows and alphabet press functionality also.

I would prefer to have angular specific implementation or a plugin, rather than **js** or **jQuery**

Comment: you can use click event to click the arrow. what is the issue now?

Comment: If open to use plugin lib this would be best https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/dropdown

Comment: its not about the click event on arrows mate @Chellappan

Comment: you mean nested dropdown?

Comment: Here's a basic implementation. I've just thrown it together, so there's likely to be a few bugs, but it should give you a good idea of where to start. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-a3hjwy?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Answer (score 0):

There is the possibility of evaluating `keydown` and `keyup` events:

https://alligator.io/angular/binding-keyup-keydown-events/

According to this you should be able to achieve this functionality by implementing click listeners such as:

```
<div class="btn-group d-flex dropdown"
     (keydown.arrowup)="select(items[i-1])"
     (keydown.arrowdown)="select(items[i+1])"
     dropdown>
```

EDIT: so I tried this and turns out this does not work on any item on default. It works on inputs, how the example shows but I could not get i ti to work on a list by now.